# How do I override the default CFBundleVersion appVersion attribute in Google Analytis iOS SDK v3

Tags: ios, google-analytics

In the v2 version of the Google Analytics SDK for iOS you could set the appVersion string like this:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY];
tracker.appVersion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"], @"aCustomIdentifier"];
```

In the v3 version of the Google Analytics SDK the appVersion string property has been removed from GAITracker.h. There is however a couple of methods that might be what I'm looking for:

```
- (void)set:(NSString *)parameterName value:(NSString *)value;
- (NSString *)get:(NSString *)parameterName;
- (void)send:(NSDictionary *)parameters;
```

I can't find any relevant information on the [Google Analytics dev guides site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/). Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A bit cleaner solution would be to use kGAIAppVersion instead of the raw protocol string:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:kGAIAppVersion value:@"CustomVersion"];
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this issue by setting the appropriate loglevel:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
```

When I then run my application I get the following output for each request:
**(Stripped down version)**

```
2014-06-12 13:37:00.101 Application Name[0000:0a00] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.03 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (    GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:418): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&av" = "1.3.3.7";
    };
    timestamp = "2014-06-12 13:37:00 +0000";
}
```

So if you want to change the app version string you can do that like so:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:@"&av" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"], @"aCustomIdentifier"]];
```